# Javascript bundler on Shared Hosting Package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, command-line, shared-hosting

Need a bit of help understanding javascript bundlers, and how to implement them on my website (I'm a novice and I don't have a great deal of experience).

I know I need a bundler as I need to improve my site's speed, and I do understand the logic and purpose of them etc. The website's already been developed and is live on a shared hosting package (1&1/Ionos). From research, the likes of Webpack can only be installed with the command line. While I can access my hosting package via Putty, I would need to install jquery to use `npm` commands (which is forbidden) - so my question is - can I install and configure Webpack in development mode on my desktop (using Xampp or something similar), and then just upload/copy and paste the files to my hosting package, and it'll work the same?

Happy to do the research and follow online tutorials once I know what I'm meant to be doing etc. All help appreciated!

Cheers!